# MERGE - to replace ON Duplicate with sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, merge

I've predominantly used mySQL so moving over to azure and sql server I realise that on duplicate does not work.

I'm trying to do this:

```
INSERT INTO records (jid, pair, interval, entry) VALUES (1, 'alpha', 3, 'unlimited') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE entry = "limited";
```

But of course on duplicate key isn't allowed here. So MERGE is the right form.

I've looked at:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

But honestly the example is a bit excessive and eye watering. Could someone dumb it down for me to fit my example so I can understand it better?

Comment: So it means that, if 'unlimited' in entry exists, you want to update, right?

Comment: Yes if the record exists, set it to limited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do the merge you need some form of source table/table var for the merge statement. Then you can do the merging. So something along the lines of this maybe (note: not completely syntax checked, apologies in advance):

```
WITH src AS (
    -- This should be your source
    SELECT 1 AS Id, 2 AS Val
)
-- The above is not neccessary if you have a source table
MERGE Target -- the detination table, so in your case records
USING src -- as defined above
ON (Target.Id = src.Id) -- how do we join the tables
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    -- if we dont match, what do to the destination table. This case insert it.
    THEN INSERT(Id, Val) VALUES(src.Id, src.Val)
WHEN MATCHED 
    -- what do we do if we match. This case update Val
    THEN UPDATE SET Target.Val = src.Val;
```

Don't forget to read the proper syntax page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

I think this translates to your example (tm):

```
WITH src AS (
    -- This should be your source
    SELECT 1 AS jid, 'alpha' AS pair, 3 as 'interval'
)
MERGE records -- the detination table, so in your case records
USING src -- as defined above
ON (records.Id = src.Id) -- how do we join the tables
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    -- if we dont match, what do to the destination table. This case insert it.
    THEN INSERT(jid, pair, interval, entry) VALUES(src.jid, src.pair, src.interval, 'unlimited')
WHEN MATCHED 
    -- what do we do if we match. This case update Val
    THEN UPDATE SET records.entry = 'limited';
```

Comment: use caution while using `MERGE`, see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/